# How to solve the smtpjs error with gmail smtp host

Tags: javascript, email, smtp, gmail

I am working with smptjs to send email using javascript. The code was working fine until today morning.

I am getting the error *"Only elasticemail is supported as an SMTP host. To open an account please visit [https://elasticemail.com/account#/create-account?r=20b444a2-b3af-4eb8-bae7-911f6097521c"](https://elasticemail.com/account#/create-account?r=20b444a2-b3af-4eb8-bae7-911f6097521c%22)*

I tried to search for this error and unsuccessful, any help in this matter would be appreciated.

**This is my js code to send the email**

```
const name = form.elements["name"].value;
const from = form.elements["email"].value;
const companyName = form.elements["company-name"].value;
const businessType = form.elements["business-type"].value;
const isOperatingBusiness = form.elements["business"].value;

const emailBody = `<h3>Please find the details below</h3>
<hr />
<span><strong>Name:</strong> ${name}</span><br />
<span><strong>Email Address:</strong>  ${from}</span><br />
<span><strong>Contact No:</strong>  ${phone}</span><br />
<span><strong>Company Name:</strong> ${companyName}</span><br />
<span><strong>Operating Business:</strong>  ${isOperatingBusiness}</span><br />
<span><strong>Business Type:</strong>  ${businessType}</span><br /><br />
<span>Thank you,</span><br />
<span>appiGo Team</span>`;

const emailObject = {
      Host: HOST,
      Username: USERNAME,
      Password: PASSWORD,
      To: DEV_MAIL,
      From: FROM,
      Subject: `${subject} ${name}`,
      Body: emailBody,
};

Email.send(emailObject).then((message) => {
      if (message == "OK") return onSuccess();
});
```

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, due to abuse (spam / phishing) SMTPJS.com has been limited to trusted SMTP providers. Currently the recommended SMTP provider is ElasticEmail, other SMTP providers may be considered in future.

Comment: Lol. Like, everyone who runs his/her own SMTP server needs to be audited for trustworthiness? Oh well, I guess they just want to sell ElasticMail.

Answer (score 1):

Elastic Email is an Email Service Provider and you can create a free trial account here https://elasticemail.com/account#/create-account to get access to the email delivery engine and SMTP relay. With a trial, you can send up to 100 emails/day. For more, you have to pay.

That's probably the only option now with smptjs.